# Typescript `Property is missing in type`, but the type is `never`

Tags: typescript

What I want to achieve is to reference the original interface, and remove some attributes. This is my original interface:

```js
export interface IInvitations {
    parent: Parse.User;
    visitor: Visitors;
    dates: IInvitationDateAndPin[];
}
```

When a user initiates the invitation, he should not give `parent` as a parameter. which will be auto-assigned before saving into the database. So I made a new interface to omit it:

```js
export interface ICInvitations extends IInvitations {
    parent: never;
}
```

But then I cannot successfully assign value to this interface.

```js
let data: ICInvitations = {
    visitor: Visitors,
    datas: [...]
}
```

It shows `Property 'parent' is missing in type`. But the type is never, which I failed to assign anything into it.

Comment: You cannot remove a property in a derived type, you may only add to it. If you want to hide those members, you'll have to use composition to hide the instance and expose only the members you want. Either that or invert your interfaces or some other approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned, while you can't remove the property from the interface, you can reuse most of it by doing something like this (`Omit` is shipped with TypeScript 3.5):

```
export interface ICInvitations extends Omit<IInvitations, 'parent'> {
  parent?: never;
}
```

The `parent?: never` part is optional, but will let you get an error if anyone tries to construct something implementing this interface with a value set for `parent`.