Unable to use "never" in union compound type
I'm trying to initialize a class with an object as the input of the constructor, which will populate a field of the class.
However, the object can have one of two fields populated, which leads to an error when I'm trying to parse it inside the constructor.
I'm expecting the following (simplified) code to work:
type Props = { name: string; age: never } | { name: never; age: number };

class Person {
  data: Props;

  constructor(data: Props) {
    if (data.name !== undefined) {
      this.data = data;
    } else {
      this.data = { // This line raises the error
        ...data,
        age: data.age * 1.5, // Even when it's just "data.age" it still raises an error
      };
    }
  }
}

But I'm getting the following error:

Type '{ age: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: never; age: number; }'.Types of property 'name' are incompatible.Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.


Why wouldn't you just use { name?: string, age?: number }?

I think you just need to do { name: string } | { age: number; }

The fields I have are mutually exclusive, so I just want to be more specific with the type definition

Using a Person with an age and name is an odd example? If this is a more complex type, you should use a different example.

If a property is of type never, but is not optional, then it will be required… but no value can satisfy the requirement:
TS Playground
const noName: { name: never } = {}; /* Error
      ~~~~~~
Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ name: never; }'.(2741) */

However, if the property is optional then there's no problem:
const noName: { name?: never } = {}; // Ok

So, to fix your example, just mark the excluded properties as optional, and everything will compile:
TS Playground
type Props =
  | { name: string; age?: never }
  | { name?: never; age: number };


Thank you, that's super helpful! I just found a relatively similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470291/typescript-property-is-missing-in-type-but-the-type-is-never

If you want a cleaner way to multiply the age by 1.5, you can do this..
class Person {
  data: Props;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    const input = { ...props };
    input.age = input.age != undefined ? input.age * 1.5 : input.age;
    this.data = input;
  }
}


While the core of the answer was given by @jsejcksn (thank you again!), there were some adjustments I had to do in order for the code to compile:
type Props = { name: string; age?: never } | { name?: never; age: number };

class Person {
  data: Props;

  constructor(data: Props) {
    if (data.name !== undefined) {
      this.data = data;
    } else {
      const { name, ...rest } = data; // This omits "name"
      this.data = {
        ...rest,
        age: data.age * 1.5,
      };
    }
  }
}

Another somewhat less elegant option I found was this:
class Person {
  data: Props;

  constructor(data: Props) {
    this.data = data;

    if (data.age !== undefined) {
      this.data.age = data.age * 1.5;
    }
  }
}

